# Parsing nested XML elements using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have this bellow XML elements but I have a problem to parse it. I’m using DOM parser to extract element data from each Dimension which can have one or plus Aggregation level and can have several attributes.

```
<Dimensions>
    <Dimension name="Time" refD="ID-T">
        <Aggregation_level>
            <level> second </level>
            <level> Minute </level>
            <level> Hour </level>
            <level> Day </level>
            <level> Month </level>
            <level> Year </level>
        </Aggregation_level>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension name="Place" refD="ID-PL">
        <aggregation_level>
            <level> Place_type </level>
        </aggregation_level> 
        <aggregation_level>
            <level> Country-code </level>
            <level_attribute>country</level_attribute>
        </aggregation_level> 
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute>Full_Name</Attribute>
            <Attribute>Name</Attribute>
            <Attribute>URL_PL</Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Dimension>
</Dimensions>
```

This is my code :

```
 NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Dimensions");
    // extract liste des dimensions 
   Element element = (Element) nodes.item(0);
   NodeList dimensionList = element.getElementsByTagName("Dimension");

   for (int i = 0; i < dimensionList.getLength(); i++) {
       Element dimensionElement = (Element) dimensionList.item(i);
       System.out.println(dimensionElement.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
       NodeList levels = dimensionElement.getElementsByTagName("Aggregation_level");
       NodeList attributs = dimensionElement.getElementsByTagName("Attributes");
       Element level = (Element)levels.item(0);
       Element attribute = (Element) attributs.item(0);
       System.out.println("verification1");
       while(level.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && level.hasChildNodes()) {
       for(int j=0; j< level.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++){

           System.out.println(level.getElementsByTagName("level").item(j).getTextContent());
           }
       }
           while(attribute.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && attribute.hasChildNodes()) {
           for(int j1=0; j1< attribute.getChildNodes().getLength(); j1++){

               System.out.println(attribute.getElementsByTagName("Attribute").item(j1).getTextContent());

           }
      }}
```

**but I receive  this result:**

> Time  second  Minute  Hour  Day  Month  Year  Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   ParsingJson.main(ParsingJson.java:45)

Comment: I cannot recreate issue with posted code and xml. The following output prints out with no error: *Time \n verification1 \n second \n Minute \n Hour \n Day \n Month \n Year \n*

Comment: But I have NullPointerException I can't pass to the second dimension to show `place` element content

Comment: I do not understand your issue. Unless you are referring to code not posted here, I cannot recreate the *NullPointerException*. What is line 45 that error refers to?